# How to mount Volume to AWS Beanstalk Deployed Docker Container

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a docker container web application which works on port 8443 (used for admin console), 9443(application traffic) deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. this application needs a configuration file which we upload from the admin console of this application itself which gets stored in docker container folder.

So now the problem , Now if I use a HA pair in a load-balanced setup in Elastic Beanstalk I need both the EC2 instances the same config file which gets stored in /usr/local/myapplciation/localstorage/.

Update - We are following the EFS mount route to store that config file now however getting below error while mounting EFS volume.

We are following this article.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-mount-efs-volumes-app/

2023-03-16 08:49:40,088 P1000 [INFO]     Mounting EFS filesystem fs-0b8e45325rt8e3647 to directory /efs ...
2023-03-16 08:49:40,088 P1000 [INFO]     Stopping NFS ID Mapper...
2023-03-16 08:49:40,088 P1000 [INFO]     rpc.idmapd is already stopped!
2023-03-16 08:49:40,088 P1000 [INFO]     Checking if EFS mount directory exists...
2023-03-16 08:49:40,088 P1000 [INFO]     Creating directory /efs ...
2023-03-16 08:49:40,088 P1000 [INFO]     mount -t efs -o tls fs-0b8e45325rt8e3647:/ /efs
2023-03-16 08:49:40,088 P1000 [INFO]     Mount attempt 1/3 failed due to timeout after 15 sec, wait 0 sec before next attempt.
2023-03-16 08:49:40,088 P1000 [INFO]     Mount attempt 2/3 failed due to timeout after 15 sec, wait 0 sec before next attempt.
2023-03-16 08:49:40,088 P1000 [INFO]     b'mount.nfs4: Connection reset by peer'
2023-03-16 08:49:40,088 P1000 [INFO]     ERROR: Mount command failed!
2023-03-16 08:49:40,088 P1000 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------
2023-03-16 08:49:40,088 P1000 [ERROR] Exited with error code 1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Store Images and Data's in S3 use S3 integrations Instead of mounting volume
For NodeJs S3 Uploads: https://flaviocopes.com/node-aws-s3-upload-image/
For PHP Laravel S3 Upload: https://www.tutsmake.com/upload-file-to-aws-s3-bucket-in-php/

Refer the above docs or Use the **Alternative and Best Solution** For this Below Recommended

You have to create a **Elastic Block Store** volume first in the same Availability Zone (AZ) as the EB environment. You can create an EBS volume in the AWS Management Console, AWS CLI, or AWS SDKs.

Create a file named 01_mount.config in the .ebextensions directory of your application source code. This file should contain the following YAML configuration:

```
commands:
  01_mount:
    command: "mkdir -p /path/to/mount && mount /dev/xvdf /path/to/mount"
```

Replace /path/to/mount with the path on the Docker container where you want to mount the volume, and replace /dev/xvdf with the device name assigned to the EBS volume.

Deploy the EB to mount the volume